# Using "convert-excel-to-json" to extract a value in excel and assign to variable?

Tags: node.js, json, excel

Im learning how to use installed npm module "convert-excel-to-json" to extract one cell value in excel and assign to a variable in node. My excel workbook has 8 values (A1 to A8) & called sheet1. Here is the code:

```
'use strict'
const fs = require('fs')
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json')

const result = excelToJson({ source: fs.readFileSync('excel-action-buffer.xlsx') })
console.log(result)
```

The output is:

```
{ Sheet1:
   [ { A: 'ENDPOINT',
       B: 'OPTIONS',
       C: 'METHOD',
       D: 'SIZE',
       E: 'PRICE',
       F: 'SIDE',
       G: 'PRODUCT',
       H: 'FUNDS' } ] }
```

How would you assign one of these values to a variable? Iv read the documentation but the methods seem to be for more advanced filtering where I am just pulling a value from an array. So i.e 'console.log(result.price) returns undefined??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRICE is the value, and the keys needed to access it are the sheet name, row index, and column name :

```js
var result = { Sheet1: [ { A: 'ENDPOINT', B: 'OPTIONS', C: 'METHOD', 
    D: 'SIZE', E: 'PRICE', F: 'SIDE', G: 'PRODUCT', H: 'FUNDS' } ] };
    
console.log( result.Sheet1[0].E );
```

Comment: Thank you Slai. Im still learning, this will help alot in the future!